# WHERE in NOT EXISTS clause being ignored

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to fill a table with rows that should be there: If a city in `@Maps` does not exist in `@Results`, then I will fill it using `NOT EXISTS`. The issue is that the filter`isused = 1` not only is ignored, it seems to void the `NOT EXISTS`.

With `IsUsed = 1`, everything in @Maps will be inserted to @Results regardless if it exists or not.

If I remove `IsUsed = 1`, both rows from *NY* are inserted (correct behavior but not what I'm looking for).

Here's the code:

```
declare @Maps table
(
    Name varchar(20),
    IsUsed bit,
    Code varchar(20)
)

insert into @Maps
select 'NY', 1, 'NY1'
union select 'NY', 0, 'NY2'
union select 'FL', 0, 'FL1'
union select 'TX', 0, 'TX1'

declare @Results table 
(
    Name varchar(20),
    Value int,
    Code varchar(20)
)
insert into @results
select 'FL', 12, 'FL1'
union
select 'TX', 54,'TX1'
union
select 'CA', 54,'CA1'
union
select 'NJ', 54,'NJ1'

insert into @results
select Name, 999, code from @Maps m
-- This adds everything even if it exists
where not exists (select name from @Results p where p.name = m.name and IsUsed = 1)
-- This adds both 'NY'. Partially correct but adds column IsUsed = 0
-- where not exists (select name from @Results p where p.name = m.name)

select * from @results
```

How can I add the one row that's not included in `@results` and has IsUsed equal to 1? In this case it would be `{'NY', 1, 'NY1`}`.

I understand that there are many ways of accomplishing this, but I'm interested in knowing how the `where` clause in `not exists` work.

Comment: I've edited. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `IsUsed=1` from the `NOT EXISTS` and add it to the `WHERE`:

```
insert into @results
select Name, 999, code 
from @Maps m
where m.IsUsed = 1
and not exists (select name from @Results p where p.name = m.name)
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thanks.

Comment: Why is it ignoring the the filter if it's inside the `not exists`?

Comment: @rbhat - The query you were using should give error because column `IsUsed` does not exist in `@Results` and your `NOT EXISTS` part should have error !

Comment: @rbhat: well, because the `NOT EXISTS` condition is met, there is no record in `@Results` which has the `NY`-name from map, `IsUsed` is irrelevant because the first condition is already false. You want to filter on `@Maps` so you should include the `IsUsed` filter there.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But on the second NY that part would be true

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir: it's perfectly fine to access columns from the main table in a sub-query/`NOT EXISTS`. Otherwise `p.name = m.name` would be invalid too. It doesn't make sense but you are allowed to use `IsUsed = 1` even if that column is not part of that table.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Even without using the alias `m.IsUsed` ?

Comment: @Paparazzi: Why? There is still no record in `@Results` with a name `NY`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, when I include IsUsed clause, everything's added even if it's included already in `@results`

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir: you can copy/paste and you'll see it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse how an `insert` `select` works.  The select is run independently.   The insert is not committed until the end of the statement.   See all the inserted cnt is 4.

```
declare @maps table(name varchar(10), isUsed bit, code varchar(10));
insert into @Maps values 
       ('NY', 1, 'NY1')
     , ('NY', 0, 'NY2')
     , ('FL', 0, 'FL1')
     , ('TX', 0, 'TX1')

declare @Results table (Name varchar(20), Value int, Code varchar(20), cnt int)
insert into @results values
       ('FL', 12, 'FL1', null)
     , ('TX', 54, 'TX1', null)
     , ('CA', 54, 'CA1', null)
     , ('NJ', 54, 'NJ1', null)

select * from @results;
insert into @Results
select m.Name, 999, m.code 
     , (select count(*) from @results) as cnt 
  from @Maps m 
 where not exists (select name 
                     from @Results p 
                    where p.name = m.name 
                      and m.IsUsed = 1) 
select * from @results;
```

On the first NY `where p.name = m.name` is false so `not exits` is true

On the second NY `where p.name = m.name` is false so `not exits` is true
The first NY as not been committed

On the FL and TL the `where p.name = m.name` is true but `m.IsUsed = 1` is false so `not exits` is true